# Outlook DASL - skip when sender and receiver are same

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to use DASL query to filter for those emails where the sender and recipient are not same. Tried the below but does not seem to work. Am i doing anything wrong here please?

I get an error message 'Cannot Parse condition at....'

```
Dim PR_RECEIVED_BY_NAME as String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0040001E"
Dim PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME as String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001E"

strFilter = "@SQL=" & "%last7days(urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived)% AND (" & PR_RECEIVED_BY_NAME & "<>" & PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME & ")
```

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, OOM does not support comparing two properties in queries, only a property with a constant - that would (on the Extended MAPI level) require `RES_COMPAREPROPS` restriction support, which OOM does not provide.

As usual, you'd need Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (any language - I am its author) for that.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to sort the collection before running any restrictions.
2. Instead of using the `last7days` I'd suggest using a condition like this:

```
"@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" <" & Format("6/10/2020 3:30pm", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
```

3. You need to use double quotes around DASL names, for example:

```
filter = "@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f"" = 'can''t'"
```

4. Try to use a single property name in the search criteria by getting the other property value and using it as a constant. Hope it helps.

Comment: Keeping aside the date factor, tried just the DASL. But still no luck


    strFilter = "@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0040001E"" <> ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001E"""
'

Comment: Try to replace `<>` to `not like`.

Comment: It seems Outlook doesn't support comparing two properties in the same filter as Dmitry suggests. So, I'd suggest get the value of one of them and use a single property name and value extracted earlier.